# Selenium webdriver scripts failing when executing with Chrome or IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have automated 200+ test cases of an angular JS application. It works well with Mozilla firefox but when changing to Chrome or IE it throws errors like unable to locate element, element is not visible at this point of time etc. Why is the same xpath is not being detected using non-FF browsers.

Comment: Impossible to answer in this state. Please add more details.

Comment: Based on complexity of the page, every browser may generate DOM differently. So, xpath may not work. To find the problem, just use a simple css selector or id selector, and run your test. Also, Chrome is faster than FF, and if you do not set some time outs, it will be easiliy throw exception.

Comment: @Turcia : Thanks. By adding wait it worked